# Eliminate data from active dataprovider in Yii2

Tags: yii2

I'm looking for a way to rotate via data in `ActiveDataProvider` and erase some rows. I have rather peculiar data structure and I can't get precise data I need with `->andFilterWhere`

I know it is possible to use `SqlDataProvider` but I would prefer to get to know a way to be able to do foreach on every row in `ActiveDataProvider` and just unset those ones I don't need.

I'm not pasting my code - I use rather simple controller and model generated via Gii - so nothing crazy here.

Will be really glad if anyone could point me into the right direction.

Comment: Unseting records from DataProvider results may give you weird results, like incorrect number of records on page (or even empty pages). You should adjust query conditions and filter these records on SQL level.

Comment: Thank you. I know I should do that but my query is quite complicated and to say it bluntly honest - I was not able to put it into provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider(['query' => $query]);

        foreach ($dataProvider->models as $model) {
            //your logic
        }
```

Comment: Thank you - this may be a good lead. With one problem though. As I'm trying to erase some rows I'm getting error.    It says: "Indirect modification of overloaded property yii\data\ActiveDataProvider::$models has no effect"     . My code is as follows:                                                                   $i = 0;
            foreach ($dataProvider->models as $model) {

                if ($model->customer_id > 50) { unset($dataProvider->models[$i]); }
                $i++;

            }

Answer (score 0):

ok, I have found an answer, so I thought I'd share.

To still be able to use active dataprovider and make a funky sql query I want the long way - I prepared a prequery which gave me only id's of rows I wanted and then I passed them into normal search query in ActiveDataProvider's search.

```
    $query->andFilterWhere([
        'customer_id' => $tempids,
```

This way what I got was - I limited the main query only to preselected rows.

Comment: This may be really slow if list of IDs returned by temp query is big - you may consider using subquery instead.

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`getModels()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-data-basedataprovider#getModels()-detail) and [`setModels()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-data-basedataprovider#setModels()-detail) to modify  list of models available in data provider:

```
$models = $dataProvider->getModels();
foreach ($models as $index => $model) {
    if (/* some condition */) {
        unset($models[$index]);
    }
}

$dataProvider->setModels($models);
```

But this is inefficient (you're creating unnecessary models) and will does not work correctly with pagination (you may get less records on page than you want, including edge case with empty page). It is better idea to filter records on query level - if you're able to filter them using SQL, you should be able to do this using `ActiveQuery`. It should be possible to add most conditions using [`andWhere()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-query#andWhere()-detail), including handling subquery:

```
$subquery = (new Query())->from(/* ... */)-> // ... rest of conditions

$dataProvider->query->andWhere(['customer_id' => $subquery]);
```